# Do we need client-side flow or server-side flow or both to implement the login with facebook feature?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

Currently on my website, users login with their login id and password, they are also required to enter their `email` when they register. Both `login_id` and `email` column on the `users` table have unique index. `users` table also stores other data associated with the user such as `gender`,`last_name`,`first_name` but these are optional (nullable) fields.

There are two changes I would like to make to the website.

The first one is, users can use their email (in addition to `login_id`) to login. For new users, when they register, they no longer need to provide a `login_id` because they will be using their email to login.

The second change is, they can login with facebook. For new users, if they login with facebook for the first time, their facebook uid will be obtained and stored in my database. This means I will have to add a `facebook_uid` column on the `users` table.

For existing users, when they login with facebook for the first time, I should first obtain their email address from their facebook profile and then check if there already exists a record using that email in the `users` table, if yes, their facebook uid will also be stored on the `facebook_uid` column on that record.

According to facebook, its platform supports two different OAuth 2.0 flows for user login: server-side flow and client-side flow. Which one or both is required for this use case?

Also, what problems can be anticipated when I implement the features like I describe above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take either approach for this, it's entirely up to you. Both methods will give you the data you need, it's a question of how comfortable you are working on the back vs front end. You just need to ask for permission to access to the user's email address.

Problems that could happen: I'm not sure but there may be legal restrictions on storing the user's Facebook ID. Also, what if someone (not me, an evil person!) registers with my email address and you don't validate that they really have access to that address - then when I log in via Facebook, the app will assume we're the same person and the evil hacker now has access to my account. Unlikely scenario but could happen...